# How to record background music while recording videos with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to record the video and background music without the microphone permission on Mobile devices.

It just like TikTok.

I know how to record stream by MediaRecorder.

But MediaRecorder only can record one stream, I don't know how to mix music in the stream.

My code:

```js
record = (renderer, fps = 25, ms = 3000, mediaElement) => new Promise(resolve => {
    if (this.recording) {
      resolve(false);
    }
    this.recording = true;
    try {
      const stream = mediaElement.captureStream(fps);
      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      const chunks = [];
      recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
      recorder.onstop = () => resolve(new Blob(chunks));
      recorder.start();
      setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), ms);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('failed to record', err);
      resolve(false);
    }
    this.recording = false;
  });
```

Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MediaRecorder: Record from Multiple Microphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059324/mediarecorder-record-from-multiple-microphones)

Comment: @MaximMazurok , Almost.  Thank you, I find the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
Need to change the audio source to stream and mix it to one stream.
It work!

```js
  record = (stream, fps = 25, ms = 3000) => new Promise(resolve => {
    if (this.recording) {
      resolve(false);
    }
    this.recording = true;
    try {
      const audio = new Audio();
      audio.src = require('someMusic.mp3');
      const context = new AudioContext();
      const backgroundMusic = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      audio.volume = 0.8;
      audio.play();
      const mixedOutput = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
      backgroundMusic.connect(mixedOutput);
      const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      const mixedTracks = mixedOutput.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
      const streamN = new MediaStream([mixedTracks, videoTrack]);
      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(streamN);
      const chunks = [];
      recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
      recorder.onstop = () => resolve(new Blob(chunks));
      recorder.start();
      setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), ms);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('failed to record', err);
      resolve(false);
    }
    this.recording = false;
  });
```